# User input multple values assigned to 1 variable BATCH

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, batch-processing

MY BATCH FILE LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
ECHO OFF

SET /P colu= Enter column name:
SET /P sn= Enter ID (Press enter when finished): 

 if %sn%={ENTER}
  GOTO START

  :START
sqlcmd -U USER -P PWORD -S  SERVER -d DBNAME-i sqlSCRIPT.sql -o LOG.txt 
-v delete=colu d_id=sn
```

I want the user to be able to enter multiple ids in a single line. Those ID's will be deleted from the DB using the **sqlScript.sql**  however this code is not allowing me to enter multple ids.

It is looking at the values I enter as 1 whole value.

For an example if I enter **1,2,3** (as separate values) it sees it as '1,2,3' as 1 whole value.

Comment: Well, you can create an array based on the delimiter and loop through that.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `if` statement, what is it intended for?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

- the variables `colu` and `sn` should be cleared at the beginning to avoid using some former value;
- the `if` clause has no sense, and the syntax was wrong;
- to use values of a variable, you need to expand them like `%colu%`;
- to use one value after another, use a `for` loop;
- there is a line-break in the middle of the `sqlcmd` command line;

The following should do what you want:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET colu=
SET sn=
SET /P colu= Enter column name:
SET /P sn= Enter ID (Press enter when finished): 

FOR %%I IN (%sn%) DO (
  sqlcmd -U USER -P PWORD -S SERVER -d DBNAME-i sqlSCRIPT.sql -o LOG.txt -v delete=%colu% d_id=%%I
)
```

Comment: do I separate the values entered by columns or spaces? When I tried spaces the program still looked at both values as 1 whole value.

Comment: the following separators should work: *space* `,` `;` `=`

Comment: According to `FOR /?`, the default delimiter set is space and tab.

Comment: @Liturgist, you are confusing `for /F` and plain `for`: `for %%I in (set) do ...` -- the `set` parameter uses the standard `cmd` delimiters...

Answer (score -1):

Use the `FOR` loop an set set a comma(,) as the delimiter then use another `FOR` loop to process the SQL commands for each i.d